# BizTalk: XSLT versus mapping tool

Tags: xslt, biztalk

We're doing a mapping process from an XML file generated by a legacy system to EDI 834/837 files. We have BizTalk 2010 and are using the Microsoft built in EDI schemas.

The EDI files are fairly complex, and the XML file we are getting is also complex, with a lot of pieces bolted on. I started going through the mapping tool, but it seemed like there was a lot of repitition that I could eliminate by running the XML file through an XSLT.

I found the following link, but I'm not happy with just one source. http://blog.eliasen.dk/2009/07/08/CustomXSLTScriptingFunctoidOrBuiltinFunctoidsAQuestionAboutReligion.aspx

So, any other advantages on using the mapping tool over just building a custom XSLT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My experience with BizTalk maps is that things that are very simple to do with XSLT can be very complex with maps.

For good counter-examples of BizTalk maps, look at the book "Pro Mapping in BizTalk Server 2009". The book has some examples of very complex things you can achieve with BizTalk maps, but the downside to it is that in fact they have hidden all the complexity in scripting functoids. Therefore, the maps are not visual at all anymore (they don't even have links between nodes to provide at least hints to deduce what the map is doing).

XSLT can be more visual than a map, since you can see the resulting XML in the XSLT (keep in mind that "text" does not imply "not visual" - if you are transforming between text formats, then a natural way to visualize the transformation is by looking at text)

BizTalk maps can be used for very simple mappings, where you are essentially copying a set of properties from one structure to another structure with the same properties. However, as soon as you have to map a structure to another different structure, you quickly get something that's hard to write AND hard to read/understand.

Answer (score 3):

Not really, I prefer XSLT too. It's easier to document (using comments in the source) and therefore to maintain. However, keep in mind that in BizTalk 2006 R2 [you could not import external XSLTs](http://blog.fabiomarini.co.uk/2008/12/concatenating-multiple-maps.html), which reduces your options for reuse. I have no idea if this has changed in subsequent versions of BizTalk, that's for you to find out and perhaps let us all know...

Comment: I'm pretty sure in 2009 that is still the case, not being able to import, which leads to some repeating.  It seems to be a common theme, easy maps = mapper, complex maps = custom xslt.  I agree though, I almost prefer custom most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, more sharing of expierence;

In my team we've had discussion on this issue. The argument for maps was that it is understood by most colleagues (as it is touched by every basic BizTalk training), and XSLT not.

I've personally worked with XSLT for a long time, before i started working with BizTalk, and find the mapper tool very .. unintuitive. Every connection i make raises more questions than it gives me comfort in knowing what the result is. What happens when the source node is nil, not present, or repeating? Whathappens when the target node is defined as minOccurs=2? What does the table mapping functoid do exactly? What does the table value extract functoid do when a value is not found? How do i create a node with an autonumbering sequence, and how do i relate other created nodes that can relate to those nodes by using the generated number?

Working with XSLT gives me the control back, i know exactly what happens.

XSLT maps have the added value of being text-based, wich works well with branching and mering in source control, and allows us to add coments in the sources. Ever tried to merge changes from a map from two diffrent branches?

End result is that we now prefer XSLT for mapping, but not every developer is fluent in XSLT. That requires some training.

One last tip: invest in unit test tooling for your maps. Find an open source toolkit, or write some plumbing to test your maps yourself. Most BizTalk artifacts are perfectly testable, even when it doesn't seem that way, with possible exception for orchestrations (which you should use as a last resort only anyway).

Answer (score 0):

IMO:

**Benefits of XSLT**

- You get better DRY by reusing mapping functionality using XSLT apply + call
  templates and custom script functions (e.g. C# script) in the same
  map. Unfortunately AFAIK `<xsl:include>` doesn't work, so you will
  need to  copy-paste to get reuse across multiple map xslt files.
- XSLT native call templates tend to be more performant than C# script (which is how most of the [functoids are implemented anyhow](http://www.bizbert.com/bizbert/2008/02/09/Understanding+The+BizTalk+Mapper+Part+3+String+Functoids.aspx))
- You can use the [XSLT debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255605%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in Visual Studio.
- And to emphasize ckarras' point that for complex maps, XSLT is actually *easier* to understand than a visual spider web.

**Benefits of Visual Map**

- Productivity for trivial maps, e.g. where all elements are exactly the same name and type and can be mapped at the root level, or if you need a dummy map with hard coded output element values.
- And I guess the hurdle rate for XSLT may be quite high.

Answer (score 0):

As someone with experience in both BizTalk as well as another GUI-based mapping tool (BridgeGate), I can say that for the non-programmer these applications contain solutions in the form of their mapping interface to solve most problems. When they fall short, they offer a back door to exit to a more code-based solution in the form of a scripting functoid. So while XSLT is certainly an alternative, I find that those who prefer it often are those with more comfort writing code than those who are not.

My experience specifically with 837P and 837I files was with the prior mapping tool (BridgeGate), and it WAS arduous--but that was mainly the fault of the complexity of the file. What I CAN say and what is not being mentioned is that changes later to the process to accommodate client change requests WAS much easier in the GUI-based maps; I can only imagine how it would have been to have to dive into an XSLT big enough to handle 837 transformations and make changes to touch every node involved with a change request. You know how big an 837 is, and how complex the looping can be. Keep that in mind when making your choice.

I don't envy your task, but know the satisfaction when you complete it will make it all worthwhile. Good luck!