# What is biztalk complex mapping?

Tags: .net, integration, biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-mapper

I have gone through many sites including MSDN but could not get the proper understanding about complex mapping in Biztalk.

Anyone can help me with some examples would be good.

Comment: Possibly you are referring to the ability to map [multiple input messages into a single output message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929518/creating-biztalk-map-with-multiple-input-schema), 
or the realization that non-trivial mapping using the mapping tool resembles a spider web and is [better expressed in an XSLT map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425527/biztalk-xslt-versus-mapping-tool).

Comment: Here's another MS definition, viz ['involves records or fields that occur multiple times for a single instance of the Record or Field Element node in the schema tree'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578721(v=bts.10).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If mapping is not straight forward and the last option is to use special functoids (like script functoids or inline xslt), we can consider it as complex.

Complex schemas also can result to complex mapping. like mapping edifact to IDOC (sap) vice versa. Or IDOC to cXML.